# Cloudflare Workers: request is not defined

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to use Cloudflare Workers to auto-select a value on a dropdown based on the user's country (using Cloudflare's `request.cf.country`).

This is the code I wrote:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  let html_content = ""
  html_content += "<p> Detected Country: " + request.cf.country + "</p>"

  let html = `${html_content}
  
<select id="edit-field-country" ><option value="_none"></option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom</option></select>
<script>
    document.getElementById('edit-field-country').value = request.cf.country;
</script>
`

  return new Response(html, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
    },})
}
```

This part is working well and it's correctly outputting the country code:

```
<p> Detected Country: " + request.cf.country + "</p>
```

Unfortunately the auto-selection doesn't work because there's a problem here:

```
document.getElementById('edit-field-country').value = request.cf.country;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I define `request.cf.country` earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.cf.country` is not defined in the context you are trying to access it (browser).

Try changing this:

```
 let html = `${html_content}
  
<select id="edit-field-country" ><option value="_none"></option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom</option></select>
<script>
    document.getElementById('edit-field-country').value = request.cf.country;
</script>
`
```

to this instead:

```
 let html = `${html_content}
  
<select id="edit-field-country" ><option value="_none"></option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom</option></select>
<script>
    document.getElementById('edit-field-country').value = '${request.cf.country}';
</script>
`
```